# How to add log statements in bolts

Tags: apache-storm

I want to add some logging statements in the `b-0 bolt` to confirm if I'm  getting any non-tick tuples in the execute method.

How can I do that?

```
storm-version -0.9.0.1
```

I got after debug is true, I used **logviewer** by click on port number of spout in Storm UI

```
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
2016-01-19 16:55:25 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [5]
```

Is that means working good? What does `[5]` mean here?

Comment: Just enable debug mode via the configuration object: `Config c = new Config(); c.setDebug(true);` -- this will log all messages in your topology.

Comment: Thanks i updaated the post with the result and question ,can please take a look ?

Comment: `[5]` is the content of the tuple, ie, you have a single attribute input tuple, and the attribute value is "5". You can ignore this for tick tuples -- for data tuples it is of course important. Furthermore, you see that `source` is `__system:-1` (what is "producerId:task-id` in general -- __system and -1 indicate that it's generated by Storm an not regular data tuple) and `stream` is `__tick` (ie, the declared output stream -- __tick is Storm system stream that delivers tick tuples), thus your are only getting tick tuples here.

Comment: so how can make it reading data ?

Comment: Does your producer emit date to the correct output stream? Is the consumer correctly connected to the producer?

Comment: drpc is the responsible for emitting data , how can i check it ? i found in at the end of the drpc log file [INFO] Starting Distributed RPC servers... but this statement didn't change . is it ok ? or i should find specific statement indicate  to request the result for a tweet

Comment: I never worked with DRPC. Sorry. (Btw: your information is very sparse -- I doubt you will get help like this. You need to extend your question with more details about your setup including code snippets -- just a suggestions to you).

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax for your help , Sure i'll do that